# Varying Error Bar Length In Timeplot Graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a quick question about the Error Bars functionality in LaTeX, specifically - I am using pgfplots and tikzpicture packages. I was wondering if it is possible to vary the length of the Error bar in each given observation? I am trying to have the length of the error bar gradually increase with each observation. My current data-set is a plot of price through time and I am loading the data-set to LaTeX using a delimited text file.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check Section 4.12 of the documentation for [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) version 1.10. Specifically keys `x explicit` and `x explicit relative` (and variants in `y` and `z`).

Comment: would you like to write an answer so this post is useful for future visitors? Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 2):

`pgfplots` has several possibilities for plotting error bars. Each of them, along with the associated styling keys, is described in Section 4.12 of the [`pgfplots` manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots).

Here I illustrate relative errors, explicit errors, and fixed errors:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot+[error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y fixed=0.1] 
    coordinates {
      (0.0,0.0)
      (0.1,0.1)
      (0.2,0.2)
      (0.5,0.5)
      (1.0,1.0)
    };
  \addplot+[error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y fixed relative=0.1] 
    coordinates {
      (0.0,0.5)
      (0.1,0.6)
      (0.2,0.7)
      (0.5,1.0)
      (1.0,1.5)
    };
  \addplot+[error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit] 
    table[x=x,y=y,y error=error] {
      x   y   error
      0.0 1.0 0.20
      0.1 1.1 0.15
      0.2 1.2 0.20
      0.5 1.5 0.22
      1.0 2.0 0.18
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The procedure/syntax is quite similar to the last plot when retrieving data from plain text files.